# How do you search subnodes in Pinfo?

Tags: macos, pinfo

I installed [Zsh`s info manuals](http://zsh.sunsite.dk/Doc/).

I run

```
pinfo zsh
```

I would like find the manual for `typeset`.

I type in pinfo

```
/typeset
```

It only searches the current screen.

**How can you search all other nodes too in Zsh's manuals in Pinfo?**

Comment: This is specific to pinfo, not zsh. Can somebody retag, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what various configuration settings are.  In my `/etc/pinforc` there is:

```
...
KEY_TOTALSEARCH_1='s'
...
KEY_SEARCH_AGAIN_1='f'
...
```

So pressing '`s`' lets me enter a search expression, and then pressing '`f`' finds the next match within all nodes and so on.

You can set these within your own `~/.pinforc`, too.

Comment: These keys are defaults for me. And "f" works following a "/".

Comment: I get the following bug after searching with `s`. When try to move, it puts those codes to my manual directly. Otherwise, the commands seems to work. http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/pinfo-bug.png